# why is recreate is looping infinity?

Tags: android

I have a simple program that changes the background of activity A from activity B. 
When you change the background you need to refresh activity A in order for the background to change, after looking around stackoverflow the easiest way was just to call recreate().

I'm not sure if im calling it wrong or in the wrong area but what ends up happening is it will loop the following error when the app is run and eventually crash-

```
02-01 13:23:53.358 17302-17302/com.package.www.randomapp E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Here's the code for activity A

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);
    backgroundChanger();
    recreate();
}

   public void backgroundChanger(){
    SharedPreferences sharedGradients = getSharedPreferences("gradientInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int backgroundGrad = sharedGradients.getInt("backgroundGradient", 0);


    if (backgroundGrad == 0){
        MMBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blackgreengradiant);




    }
    if (backgroundGrad == 1){
        MMBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blueblackgradiant);


    }
    if (backgroundGrad == 2){
        MMBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goldblackgradiant);


    }
```

and for Activity B

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options_menu);
    variableHandler();
}

 public void variableHandler() {  

    MainMenuBackgroundBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            final SharedPreferences[] sharedGradients = {getSharedPreferences("gradientInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)};
            final SharedPreferences.Editor[] editor1 = {sharedGradients[0].edit()};

            final SharedPreferences[] sharedBoolean = {getSharedPreferences("binaryPoint", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)};
            final SharedPreferences.Editor[] editorBinary = {sharedBoolean[0].edit()};

            final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), v);
            popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_background_gradiant_setter);
            popup.show();


            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.item1:
                            Toast.makeText(OptionsMenu.this, "Blue and black gradient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            editorBinary[0] = sharedBoolean[0].edit();
                            editorBinary[0].putInt("binaryPoint", 1);

                            editor1[0] = sharedGradients[0].edit();
                            editor1[0].putInt("backgroundGradient", 1);
                            editor1[0].apply();



                            return true;

                        case R.id.item2:
                            Toast.makeText(OptionsMenu.this, "Gold and black gradient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            editorBinary[0] = sharedBoolean[0].edit();
                            editorBinary[0].putInt("binaryPoint", 1);

                            editor1[0] = sharedGradients[0].edit();
                            editor1[0].putInt("backgroundGradient", 2);
                            editor1[0].apply();
                            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to recreate the activity just to set the background, you can do startActivityForResult on the intent for Activity B and on the result set the background of A. Also, reading your code you don't really even need an Activity B, that could be handled in an AlertDialog or something that is prompted from Activity A.

Comment: Why are your SharedPreferences in an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `recreate()` in the `onCreate()` method of the Activity without any condition which will create an infinite loop. Keep a variable to track whether the activity is recreated or not.

```
private static boolean alreadyRecreated = false;
//You can add some extra conditions here if you want.
if(!alreadyRecreated){
  recreate();
   alreadyRecreated = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`recreate();` will cause your activity to be recreated.

i.e, onCreate gets called. Since, you added `recreate();` in onCreate method, it is running into infinite loop and crashing.